# API to know whether node is active or not

Tags: ros, node, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to know  what is the API  in roscpp which can be used whether particular node is active or not.

~can-43811

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257580/api-to-know-whether-node-is-active-or-not/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey
There's a way to get the current nodes registered with ros master using the `ros::master::getNodes(v)` This will push the names of the nodes registered into the vector of strings,  v.

```
     while (ros::ok()) 
   {
        if(!ros::master::getNodes(v))
        {
          ROS_INFO("Error");
    
        }   
         else
        {  
           //do your stuff 
        }
    }
```

You will have to include  the libraries

```
#include "ros/this_node.h" 
 #include "ros/master.h"
```

---

Originally posted by [eesttaar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22855/eesttaar/) with karma: 26 on 2017-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1